# Approximation of a Generalized Hypergeometric Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

Is there any approximation with an "elementary function" for the following generalized hypergeometric function, especially for very large values of $n$ and $0 < p < 1$? I mean, without using binomials or other special functions.

$_3F_2 \left(1, 1, 1-n; 2, 2; \frac{p}{p-1}\right)$

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you derived that answer
From the definition of generalized hypergeometric function, I obtain:
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_k(1)_k(1-n)_k}{(2)_k(2_k)}\frac{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^k}{k!}$
Then, I consider only the terms for $k$ from 1 to $n-1$.
With the definition of rising factorial, $(1)_k = k!$ and $(2)_k = (k+1)!$

Comment: Then, I remain with:
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-n)_k}{(k+1)(k+1)!}\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^k$.
So now, I transform $(1-n)_k$ in a falling factorial, so that it becomes $(-1)^k\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!}$.
I can pull out from $\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^k$ the minus sign so that I have $(-1)^k\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k$, and I can simplify the two $(-1)^k$.
Finally, I multiply and divide by $n$, so that I obtain:
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!p^k}{(n-1-k)!(k+1)(k+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^k$.
But now? Can you help me... I suppose there is something related to series but...

Comment: Maybe it is related to the fact that $\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k$ as a geometric series converges to $1/(1-(p/(1-p)^k))$... but then...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity write $z=p/(p-1)$ and assume $p<1/2$ for having $-1<z<0$ and $1-z=\frac{1}{1-p}.$ Then
$$F_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-n)_k}{k!}\frac{z^k}{(k+1)^2}.$$ Then
$$[z(zF_n(z))']'=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-n)_k}{k!}z^k=(1-z)^{n-1}.$$ This implies that $$z(zF_n(z))'=\frac{1}{n}(1-(1-z)^n)$$$$ zF_n(z)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^z\frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}dt=\frac{1}{n}\int_{1-z}^1\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}du=\frac{1}{n}\int_{1-z}^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^kdu$$ Therefore $$F_n(z)=\frac{1}{nz}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}(1-(1-z)^k)=\frac{1-p}{np}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{(1-p)^k}-1\right)$$

Now the approximation, using the following lemma: if $R>1$ then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{R^k}{k}\sim_{n\to \infty}\frac{R^n}{n}\times \frac{R}{R-1}.$$Proof: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{R^k}{k}=\frac{R^n}{n}\times \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}\frac{1}{R^k}\leq \frac{R^n}{n}\times \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)\frac{1}{R^k}$$ Hence by dominated convergence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}\frac{1}{R^k}\to_{n\to \infty}\frac{R}{R-1}.$$ We conclude by applying the lemma to $R=1/(1-p).$ We can ignore the term $\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\frac{1}{k}\sim \frac{\log n}{n}\to 0$ and write$$F_n(\frac{p}{p-1})\sim \frac{1-p}{p^2n^2}\times \frac{1}{(1-p)^n}.$$

Finally,  to expell the hypothesis $p<1/2$, it has been done in order to garantee the convergence of the series $F_n(z)$. But the calculation has shown that $F_n(z)$ is actually a polynomial and all above holds for all $z$, in particular for all $0<p<1.$

Comment: Thank you for your great and detailed answer. Based on what I can say that it is possible to "rewrite" $F_n(z)$ starting from [(())′]′ ?  Is this a known connection, or just a trick?

Comment: And an another question is how you apply the dominated convergence? In practice, $\frac{1}{R^k}$ is a geometric series converging to $\frac{R}{R-1}$. So, how can $\frac{k+1}{R^k}$ converge to the same value? Moreover, I understand the dominated convergence for series should be:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)$, under the hypothesis that $f_n(x) < g(x)$ for each $n$ and for each $x$. So now, $\frac{k+1}{R^k}$ should be my $g(x)$, but how its convergence value is related with $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)$ or with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)$? Thank you

Comment: You are mixing the roles of $x$ and $n$ in your idea of dominated convergence. In our particular case, $0<f_k(n)\leq g(k)$,  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g_k<\infty$ and $\lim_nf_k(n)=f_k$ implies $$\lim_n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k.$$ The particular case is $g_k=(k+1)R^{-k}$ , $f_k(n)=\frac{n}{n-k}R^{-k}$ for $k<n$ and $f_k(n)=0$ for $k\geq n.$ Therefore for fixed $k$ you have $\lim_nf_k(n)=f_k=R^{-k}.$